# Ignore empty cells and skip duplicate entries in Google Sheets/Calendar sync

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script for a Google Sheets to sync to Google Calendar. My current roadblock is trying to have it read all the entries in a column, ignoring the empty cells and not making duplicate entries if I run it multiple times. When I have the getRange set to anything that covers an empty cell, it will error with

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.

While it still creates the entries, I'm sure the one who will be concerned when he sees a red error saying something went wrong.

The other issue is that every time the script runs, it will duplicate entries that were copied from previous times. How do I prevent this?

Here is the current script.

```
        function onOpen() {
     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var menu = ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar');
     var item = menu.addItem('Commit', 'syncCalendar');
     item.addToUi();
    }

    function syncCalendar() {

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

      var calendarId = "*******";

      var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

      var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("D3:F10").getValues();

      for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

        var slot = signups[x];

        var startTime = slot[0];
        var endTime = slot[1];
        var name = slot[2];

        eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to remove the error as shown in your question.

  - In this case, the empty values are included in `signups`. You want to ignore these empty values.
- You don't want to create the duplicated events.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to ignore the empty values, in this case, `if (name && startTime && endTime) {}` is used.
- In order to avoid to create the duplicated events, `if (!eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime)) {}` is used.

When these are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {

  var slot = signups[x];

  var startTime = slot[0];
  var endTime = slot[1];
  var name = slot[2];

  eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);
}
```

To:

```
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
  var slot = signups[x];
  var startTime = slot[0];
  var endTime = slot[1];
  var name = slot[2];
  if (name && startTime && endTime) {  // Added
    if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).length == 0) {  // Added
      eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);
    }
  }
}
```

- In this case, all 3 values of `name`, `startTime` and `endTime` are existing, the if statement becomes `true`. If you want to modify this condition, please modify it for your actual situation.
- In above script, even when the event title is different while `startTime` and `endTime` are the same, new event is not created. If you want to create new event when the event title is different, please modify `if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime).length == 0) {` as follows.

  ```
  if (eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search: name}).length == 0) {
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getEvents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#geteventsstarttime,-endtime)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the answer to the problem!

Comment: @Shikibara Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.